# Button Click event to add TextBox to Grid

Tags: c#, silverlight

where's the problem?
I would like to add a new textbox to grid dynamically. (Silverlight)

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox o = new TextBox();
        o.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 160); // margin top, I hope.
        o.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 40); // margin left, I hope.
        o.Height = 31;
        o.Width = 140;
        o.HorizontalAlignment= HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        o.TextWrapping =  TextWrapping.Wrap;
        o.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(o);
    }
```

Thank you so much.
Regards, Daniele.

Comment: I advice always to add the textbox just make it not visible by default and on button click make it visible !

Comment: Thank you. I know, but It's not a good solution at the moment.. Because It's just up to user of my app how many textboxes he really needs. For example what If someone needed 15 textboxes? Therefore hidden (collapsed) textboxes is not the best solution.

Comment: Did you do any research? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kirtan007/add-controls-dynamically-to-silverlight-page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think LayoutRoot is a Grid in XAML:

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
```

In this case, you should remove the assignment of `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` and set the `Margin` of the `TextBox`:

```
TextBox o = new TextBox();
o.Margin = new Thickness(40, 160, 0, 0);
//...
```

`Canvas.`-properties has only an effect in the `Canvas` container. And you should use the corresponding methods to set the attached properties in codebehind:

```
Canvas.SetTop(o, 160);
```